# ImportError: No module named app.views django 1.10 python

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I just have started learning django in its 1.10 version. In a project (called `refugio`) I have created an app called `mascota`.

This is my views.py file for my app:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Index")
```

Also, I already have written my urls.py file for it:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from apps.mascota.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$/', index),
]
```

And I have modified the url.py file of my project:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('apps.mascota.urls')),
]
```

But when I run the server of my project, it sends me the next error message:
[image]

If it helps, My dir tree is the following:

`REFUGIO
    apps
        mascota
            views.py
            urls.py
    refugio
        settings.py
        urls.py
    manage.py`

I know this is a dummy question, but I don't know what is wrong, I have already checked my urls sentences, but I see everything ok.

I will appreciate your help.

Ps.: My app is located inside a folder called apps.

Regards.

Comment: That apps folder was created manually by you, right ?

Comment: Yes, I have created them manually, and also I have created the __init__.py inside the app folder

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but your url `url(r'^$/', index),` can never match anything, since it expects a slash `/` after the end of the string `$`. It should probably be `url(r'^$', index),`

Answer (score 0):

Change your file structure into

```
REFUGIO
    mascota
        views.py
        urls.py
    refugio
        settings.py
        urls.py
    manage.py
```

and then change the line in urls.py

```
from apps.mascota.views import index
```

into

```
form mascota.views import index
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In fact, I have another project where I don't organize my project using an app folder and this project is working fine, but reading the "good practices", this say that it would be better if all my apps are located inside a folder called apps. That's the reason I organize my project in this way, but now I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Every Python package need `__init__.py` file (read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)).

```
REFUGIO
    apps
        mascota
            __init__.py
            views.py
            urls.py
        __init__.py
    refugio
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
    manage.py
```

Comment: You have all files? `apps/__init__.py`, `apps/mascota/__init__.py` and `refugio/__init__.py`?